Spark Scala - read and write to parquet file and retain the original schema
In the below scala code, I am reading a parquet file, amending value of a column and writing the new dataframe into a new parquet file:
var df = spark.read.parquet(sourcePath)
val newDf = df.withColumn("my_num_field", lit(11.10))
newDf.write.parquet(targetPath)

Running the above code is generating a new parquet file with the new value 11.10 for my_num_field. However, schema type is being changed for this field and few other fields where the original schema type was:
"type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "fixed",
      "name" : "my_num_field",
      "size" : 16,
      "logicalType" : "decimal",
      "precision" : 14,
      "scale" : 3
    }

And the new data type is now:
"type" : "double"

This is producing below error when I load the parquet on HDFS and run a select query:
incompatible Parquet schema for column 'my_db.my_table.my_num_field'. Column type: DECIMAL(14,3), Parquet schema: required double my_num_field

How can I retain the original schema?
I have tried few things suggested on SOF already and still produces the same outcome:

Added cast .cast(DecimalType(14, 3) after lit(11.10).
Set overwrite schema flag during both read and write: .option("overwriteSchema","false")
Set merge schema flag: .option("mergeSchema","false") and also with and without above overwriteSchema option.


are you sure it's actually decimal for all the parquet files? the error message seems to show it's actually decimal in at least the files it's trying to write based on (e.g. some files could be corrupted).

@Chris - Yes, it's only reading a single file and writing to another file. The error in HDFS is complaining about the new file (output from the script) that is being loaded.

I think you need to create a small running test example reproduction for further help
